# Data format transfer by using Reg Ex

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a batch of strings like

```
32-1233-21323300
32-dsdw-ee322300
32-ee23-cd3de300
```

The expectation results after replacement

```
3451-1233-213.233
3451-dsdw-ee3.223
3451-ee23-cd3.de3
......
```

What I want is to use regex in a function to transfer the data format.

function dataTransfer('32-xxxx-xxxxxx00', '4351-xxxx-xxx.xxx')

My former code is like:

```
arrData(d=>{
  d = d.replace(/^[32]/,"3451").replace(/[00]$/,"");
  d = d.slice(0, 13) + '.' + d.slice(13);
})
```

But I think there should be other good solution. any suggestion?

Appendix：
Thank you for all feedback.
give up, What I want is to try to analyse format like '32-xxxx-xxxxxx00'. x stands for any char.

User can input param like 32-xxxx-xxxxxx00 and 4351-xx0x-xxx.xx9
I will get source and target format. then I try to analyse the format and use RegEx to complete the data transfer. But It seems too complicated.

Answer (score 1):

May be this regex help you. Try below regex

**"32-1233-21323300".replace(/^(32)/,"3451").replace(/([0]+)$/,"").replace(/([0-9a-zA-Z]{3})$/,".$1")**

Output : **3451-1233-213.233** as your expectation.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see why your solution is bad but if you want 1 regex instead you can use [this](https://regex101.com/r/yy5CL4/3/):

```
^(?:32)(-[\da-z]{4}-[\da-z]{3})([\da-z]{3})
```

It will produce 2 groups and then you can do `"3451"+group1+"."+group2` to create your final string

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of `/(^32)(.{9})(.{3})(00$)/`, merging substrings:

```js
const a = '32-dsdw-ee322300'.replace(/(^32)(.{9})(.{3})(00$)/, `3451$2.$3`)
console.log(a)
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need these two replace. Check this JS demo.

```js
var arr = ['32-1233-21323300','32-dsdw-ee322300','32-ee23-cd3de300']

for (s of arr) {
  console.log(s + " --> " + s.replace(/^32/,'3451').replace(/(.{3})(.{3})00$/,'$1.$2'));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do this easily without regex:

```js
    var s = "32-1233-21323300";
    if(s.startsWith("32-") && s.endsWith("00")){
      // remove 32- at the beginning
      s = "3451-" + s.slice(3);
      // remove 00 at the end
      s = s.slice(0, s.length - 2);
      // insert dot
      s = s.slice(0, s.length - 3) + "." + s.slice(s.length - 3);
      console.log(s);
    }
```